# Wordpress creates weird image sizes... :P

Tags: wordpress, image

I just noticed Wordpress creates 48x48, 96x96 and 128x128 version images, when I upload something.

But, I swear, there's nothing on my functions.php about this. Any clues of how to fix this? I don't want those images, they use a lot of space... :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was the CO-AUTHORS PLUS plugin. 
I just removed the image sizes with the functions.php and it's ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your functions.php file

> function wp_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {
>
> unset( $sizes['medium']); unset( $sizes['large']); unset(
>   $sizes['wp-newsletters-max']);
>
> return $sizes; } add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced',
>   'wp_filter_image_sizes');
>
> function wp_custom_image_sizes($sizes) { $myimgsizes = array(
>   "image-in-post" => __( "Image in Post" ), "full" => __( "Original
>   size" ) ); return $myimgsizes; } add_filter('image_size_names_choose',
>   'wp_custom_image_sizes');

Comment: With this code all I get is 32x32, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128 and the original file... :P :/